How Do I Implement A Post Like Logic For A List Of Posts
I am trying to figure out how flutter can create dynamic variables to enable me implement the LIKE feature on my App. I used the ListBuilder to list posts from my server and I want users to be able to like any of the post displayed. A page usually contain several posts with their respective LIKE buttons and LIKE count.
How do I uniquely identify each post and change their like count on click and also change the color of the like icon on click?
In php, we are able to dynamically create variables like $post_1, $post_2, $post_3 etc as we loop through the post list using the unique post_id. Is there any thing similar to this in Flutter?


you would have a modal class for each post which stores the message ids, messages etc.
